# Finding points on a plane or line in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, parametrization

I'm just getting familiar with analytical geometry and basically I have two probably very simple questions.

**Question 1:**

Let's assume I have some plane, i.e: $\pi: x - 2y + 4z - 8 = 0$

What should I do to find points on that plane?

My take on this: to find any point $P(x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0}) \in \pi $ I can assume that two out of three $x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0}$ are any constant values $\in \mathbb{R}$ and then find the value of third coordinate. For example let's assume: $x_{0} = 0, z_{0} = 8$, then:

$$0 - 2y_{0} + 32 - 8 = 0$$

$$y_{0} = 12$$

$$\Rightarrow P(0,12,8) \in \pi$$

Is that how should it be done?

**Question 2:**

Let's assume I have some line i.e.: $\displaystyle \frac{x}{2} = \frac{y - 1}{-2} = z$

I can directly see that point $P(0, 1, 0)$ will surely belong to that line. But let's say I want to find any other point(s) - how should I do it?

I suspect that I can switch the line equation into the parametric form, and then plug in for example value $5$ for parameter $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this the way to go?

Comment: You are doing fine for most cases. For a plane, be careful when you have something like $y=5$. Obviously any $(x,5,z)$ is on the plane, so don't accidentally choose $y=3$. For the line, just set different values for any of the components (as long as it's not constant). For example, just plug in $z=2$ in the line equation above.

Comment: Just as you propose switching the line into parametric form, you can switch the plane equation into parametric form, but there will be two parameters instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first idea is precisely what I would do (and have done before): on a plane, one has $2$ degrees of freedom of movement, corresponding to the fact that one has freedom in choosing values for any two of the variables$^\dagger$, and this will determine the third.  Your second idea is also what I would do, wherein the line can be parametrized as:

$$\alpha(t) = \begin{bmatrix}  2t \\ -2t + 1 \\ t \end{bmatrix}$$

The trick, for anyone feeling like I pulled this out of a hat, is to simply let any one of the variables *be* the parametrizing variable $t$.  Here, of course, we let $z=t$, and then, using the given relations, solved for the other variables so that we obtained expressions $x = f(t)$ and $y = g(t)$; these functions $f$ and $g$ serve as the $x$ and $y$ components of $\alpha(t)$ respectively. Finally, note that parametrizations of curves are *never* unique, so don't panic if a purported parametrization and yours don't perfectly visually compare.

---

P.S. if you have two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ on any line in $\mathbb{R}^n$, one can parametrize this line as $\alpha(t) = (1-t)P_1 + tP_2$.   Indeed, check that $\alpha(0) = P_1$ and $\alpha(1) = P_2$, and you can see $\alpha$ is linear because, for instance, it has constant derivative.  Parametrizing in this way has added utility: one can tell where points *are* relative to $P_1$ and $P_2$.  Note that points corresponding to $t \leq 0$ lie "before" $P_1$; points corresponding to $0 < t < 1$ lie between $P_1$ and $P_2$, and so forth.

I only mention this last bit as this discussion reminded me of a coding project I'm working on where this idea saved me *so much time* (needed to implement a subroutine that checks where a line intersects another relative to two points on the line being intersected).  Hopefully in my sharing, it serves someone equally well.

---

$^\dagger$This "...any two of the variables..." bit isn't quite true in *every* case.  For example, if the plane was horizontal with $z=1$ fixed (or, in general, when the plane is parallel to one of the planes spanned by any two of the coordinate axes), clearly one can't choose an arbitrary value for $z$ (or whichever variable is fixed).  But one nevertheless still has two degrees of choice freedom: $x$ and $y$ can be *anything*.

Comment: The line $\alpha(t)$ is not well parameterized.

Comment: Goodness, you were right.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be considered a complete answer, or if this is what you want, but I hope this is at least helpful:

**Question 1:** So, a point in that plane is a point satisfying the equation, and the way you found it is the right idea. For instance, say you fix $x,y$. Then, solve for $z$. From $x-2y+4z-8=0$. You get $z=\frac{8-x+2y}{4}$. So, any point in the plane in general will have the form $\left(x,y,\frac{8-x+2y}{4}\right)$. In particular if you choose $x=0,y=12$ you get the point you found $(0,12,8)$.

**Question 2:** You have $\frac{x}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-2}=z$. Let's write 
$\frac{x}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-2}=z=t$
And find each variable in terms of the parameter $t$. We have $x=2t$, $y=-2t+1$, $z=t$. So, any point of this line is of the form $(2t,-2t+1,t)$. In particular for $t=0$, you get the point you found $(0,1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is find just one point say v=(0,0,2) putting x and y equal to 0. Then solve x-2y+4z=0 to get {w=(a,b,(2b-a)/4)}. Your required soln set is {v+w}